How do you change the log scope of a log sink?
I have several log sinks configured to sink into a log bucket I created in one project- not the default log bucket.
Now I want to create a log sink in that project that ships logs somewhere with pub/sub.
The problem is when I try to create a sink it only lets me choose logs from the default bucket. I don't see an option to change the log scope of a project log sink to point to the bucket I created how is this possible?
I need to point it to the bucket I manually created to get logs from: "logging.googleapis.com/projects/myproject/locations/global/buckets/my_log_bucket"
I followed this doc to create and define a new default log scope but I'm still not seeing the logs in the sink. Does this not effect log sinks? https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/log-scope/create-and-manage#set-default.
EDIT
I had routing setup wrong. This is the right config:

Instead of pointing folder or project sinks to a logging bucket, sink them to the GCP project housing the bucket
Then in the centralized logging project created a sink to send all logs to the custom logging bucket
Another sink to send logs to pubsub
Disable the default log sink (maybe I don't need to do this)

The project sinks route all incoming logs so it can be used to centralize log routing. I disabled the default log sink because I was afraid I would be duplicating all the logs in the default and custom logging bucket- that would happen right?

Indeed, you can't create a sink from a log scope. But I think it's a feature, not a bug. A scope is set of log view across different project, to be able to have a single view in a single place of all your logs. There is no physical storage, routing or processing, it's just a view.
The log sink is a processing component that route the logs entry. You can have a look to the documentation here and watch the video; and you can see this diagram

In fact, the log sink is not based on a log bucket or whatever, it's directly connected to the Cloud Logging API to route the log entries to the correct destination. Because of this, you must plug your sink (or router) directly at the root of Cloud logging and not as a sub processing of a previous sink.
If you need to get logs from multiple project, you can :

either create a sink in each project that sink in the same PubSub message
or create a sink at a folder/org level and set the correct filter, and sink the result to PubSub.


I just needed to sink to a centralized project instead of a bucket. In my EDIT comment, I would be duplicating all incoming logs to the default and custom logging bucket if I didn't disable the default log bucket sync right?
